# How to apply Python Script for input generated by another processor in Nifi?

Tags: python, apache-nifi

I have incoming data from Mysql and convert into Json and do some processing in the output generating from the Nifi process.

I need to execute python script for the input generated by Nifi. 
There is a 'Execute Script' in the Nifi Processor after selecting it I have mentioned the Code and Engine.

How to apply Script for this input generated by another processor? Example if the values are separated by colon and want to change to comma . I have wrote Python script and how to apply in 'Execute Script'

Comment: Just search for nifi + python examples. https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/75032/executescript-cookbook-part-1.html

Comment: similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44630514/how-to-update-line-with-modified-data-in-jython/44631896#44631896